# Как объявить переменную в файле с расширением java, зная только путь к файлу?

Tags: java

Есть N файлов с расширением .java, в каждом объявлен какой-то класс на Java.

Как программно в каждом классе объявить некоторую переменную и инициализировать её требуемым значением?

Нужен код (или хотя бы его алгоритм), которому можно было бы передать только путь к файлу. На выходе — отредактированный файл, в котором добавлена строка

```
type myvariable = somevalue;
```

---

Оригинальный текст вопроса:

Как объявить переменную в файле с расширением java, зная только путь к файлу?
В этом файле нужно объявить эту переменную и задать ей значение, которое мне потребуется.

Comment: Я, например, не понял, что вы имеете в виду.

Comment: У меня может быть 5000 файлов с рабочим кодом на java в каждый из которых придется зайти, объявить переменную и задать значение. Думаю тогда это будет очень трудоемкий процесс.

Comment: @user200355 тут зависит от того, что это за файлы, чему принадлежат, и зачем вообще в 5000 файла одинаковая переменная О________________________О  может эти файлы у вас все наследуются от чего-то, тогда может быть у родителя можно сделать поле....... тут надо задачу смотреть и думать..... а то чую вы фигню какую-то задумали :-D

Comment: @Qwertiy почему никак? это ж обычный текстовый файл. берем перезаписываем его с данными которые нужны.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: Похоже, что ваш комментарий — это ответ. Опубликуете?

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос. В будущем постарайтесь четко формулировать условия задачи и желаемый результат.

Comment: Кстати, сама по себе такая задача бессмысленна. Если вам нужно программно редактировать сотни файлов — значит архитектура вашего приложения имеет серьёзнейшие проблемы. Подумайте например о наследовании — если переменная объявлена в родительском классе, то она сразу есть и в наследниках.

Comment: Если надо задавать столько значений, не лучше ли вынести всю в файл конфигурации?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Код на языке Java - структурированный, поэтому просто добавить строчку в произвольное место нельзя. Вначале нужно разобраться в структуре файла и добавить строчку в строго определенное место.

Для получения структурного представления документа, нужно вначале найти какой-нибудь парсер, который даст доступ до модификации [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). 
Суть в том, что мы загружаем в парсер файл, на выход получаем AST в удобной для модификации форме, создаем и добавляем новое поле, и собираем его назад в java-код.

Сложность с выбором парсера в том, что он обычно весьма сложный, и непонятно, можем ли мы доверять тому, в чем быстро не можем разобраться. В качестве иллюстрации, в данном примере я использую [JavaParser](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser), но поручиться за то, что это решение действительно хорошо поведет себя в продакшене, я не могу. Для моих небольших применений оно вполне работало.

Как можно понять по коду, нужно запускать этот пример из командной строки. Для разбора аргументов командной строки применяется вполне стандартное решение - [Apache Commons CLI](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/usage.html).

Я собрал вам готовый пример [прямо в репозитории на гитхабе](https://github.com/holy-shit/stackoverflowru-q488119), его можно собрать с помощью `mvn clean install`. Список аргументов можно узнать, запустив команду `mvn exec:java` без параметров в корне проекта. Настоящий запуск можно выполнить, указав все аргументы как-то так: `mvn exec:java -Dexec.args="-s C:\tmp\M.java -d C:\tmp\M3.java -n x -t int -i 10"` (конечно, подставив правильные значения).

Теперь перейдем к самому коду программы:

```
/**
 * Этот класс содержит в себе исполняемую из терминала программу,
 * которая читает java-файл, добавляет в него поле согласно параметрам командной строки,
 * и пишет его в исходящий java-файл.
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * Главный метод приложения
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Парсим параметры командной строки
        Optional<ParsedArgs> argzOpt = ParsedArgs.parse(args);
        if (!argzOpt.isPresent()) {
            System.out.println("Can't parse parameters, terminated.");
            return;
        }
        ParsedArgs argz = argzOpt.get();

        //Перезаписываем файл
        addVariableAndReplaceFile(argz.type, argz.varName, argz.initString, argz.srcFile, argz.destFile);

        //PROFIT
        System.out.println("All operations completed.");
    }

    /**
     * Перезаписать файл destFile содержимым srcFile с добавлением поля типа type, с именем name и инициализатором initString
     */
    public static void addVariableAndReplaceFile(String type, String name, String initString, String srcFile, String destFile) {
        //Добавляем поле, получаем новый текст класса
        Optional<String> result = addVariable(type, name, initString, srcFile);
        if (result.isPresent()) {
            try {
                //Пишем полученный текст в файл
                Files.write(Paths.get(destFile), result.get().getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(String.format("File was changed and saved to: %s", destFile));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Parser returned an empty response - probably something gone wrong!");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Вернуть строку с содержимым srcFile с добавлением поля типа type, с именем name и инициализатором initString
     */
    public static Optional<String> addVariable(String type, String name, String initString, String srcFile) {
        Optional<String> result = Optional.empty();

        //С помощью Javaparser конструируем CompilationUnit из файла
        Optional<CompilationUnit> compilationUnitOpt = Optional.empty();
        try(FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(srcFile)) {
            compilationUnitOpt = Optional.of(JavaParser.parse(in));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Определяем параметры добавляемого поля
        FieldDeclaration fieldDeclaration = new FieldDeclaration(
                ModifierSet.PUBLIC |  ModifierSet.STATIC |  ModifierSet.FINAL,
                new ClassOrInterfaceType(type),
                new VariableDeclarator(new VariableDeclaratorId(name), new NameExpr(initString))
        );

        //Добавляем поле в compilation unit
        if (compilationUnitOpt.isPresent()) {
            CompilationUnit compilationUnit = compilationUnitOpt.get();
            for (TypeDeclaration typ : compilationUnit.getTypes()) {
                ASTHelper.addMember(typ, fieldDeclaration);
            }
            result = Optional.of(compilationUnit.toString());
        }

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Класс для хранения пачки параметров командной строки для приложния, которое должно выполняться в терминале
     */
    private static class ParsedArgs {
        public String srcFile;
        public String destFile;
        public String type;
        public String varName;
        public String initString;

        public static Optional<ParsedArgs> parse(String[] args) {
            Optional<ParsedArgs> result = Optional.empty();

            try {
                //Формируем правила Apache Commons CLI
                ParsedArgs obj = new ParsedArgs();
                Options options = new Options();
                options.addOption("s", "source", true, "source file");
                options.addOption("d", "dest", true, "destination file");
                options.addOption("t", "type", true, "type of the variable");
                options.addOption("n", "name", true, "name of the variable");
                options.addOption("i", "init", true, "initialization string for the variable");

                //Парсим аргументы с помощью заготовленных правил
                CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
                CommandLine cmd = parser.parse( options, args);

                //Перебрасываем в поля класса
                obj.srcFile = cmd.getOptionValue("s");
                obj.destFile = cmd.getOptionValue("d");
                obj.type = cmd.getOptionValue("t");
                obj.varName = cmd.getOptionValue("n");
                obj.initString = cmd.getOptionValue("i");

                //Все переменные строго обязательные - если одна из них пропущена, печатаем help и выходим
                if (null == obj.srcFile || null == obj.destFile || null == obj.type
                        || null == obj.varName || null == obj.initString) {
                    HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
                    formatter.printHelp( "jaddfield", options );
                    System.out.println("ALL PARAMETERS ARE MANDATORY");

                    return Optional.empty();
                }

                result = Optional.of(obj);

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                System.out.println("Error trying to parse options");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return Optional.empty();
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Конечно же, для сборки данного проекта нужно подключить библиотеки JavaParser и CommonsCLI, и перевести компилятор в режим Java 8. Вот пример POM файла для Maven, который делает все необходимые действия:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.olegchir.stackoverflowru</groupId>
    <artifactId>q488119</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javaparser</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaparser-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Хороший ответ! +1